Teen witch movie from 80s or 90s
I watched this a long time ago so I don’t remember everything.
There’s a teenage girl going into a new school who gets half of a magic necklace which lets her get whatever she wants.
The mean girl character finds the other half and uses it against her in some way. I remember the evil girl being brunette.
I swore Rachel Leigh Cook played in it but it’s not in her movie catalog.

There was a necklace in Teen Witch, but not a second as far as I know.

Does this movie look familiar to you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Craft_(film)

Is this Teen Sorcery, from 1999?
Details which fit:

New girl in school
Magic necklace/amulet
Antagonist (played by Lexa Doig) is a brunette in the film (and could be probably be mistaken for Rachel Leigh Cook in a fuzzy memory)
Time frame is correct

Full movie seems be available for streaming in lots of places, I found it on The Archive.

TBH, wigs and dyes make hair color somewhat irrelevant, but, meeting the criteria helps.

Updated to clarify that I meant the hair color in the film itself.
